# Querying the access permissions of a gitlab access token

Tags: rest, gitlab, access-token, gitlab-api

Let's say I have a gitlab access token (generated and given to an application by a user). I can find if that token can be used to read from a repository by actually trying to read some data and seeing if that operation succeeds.

How do I find whether that token has write permissions (making commits) for a specific repository?

Comment: That would be useful to debug why a CI build fails because of token permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Beside trying a write operation, I don't know of an API which would be able to get the scope of a token.

As [this issue illustrates](https://github.com/r-lib/remotes/issues/355), the scope is what you are looking for: "[Limiting scopes of a personal access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#limiting-scopes-of-a-personal-access-token)"

Check if your token is listed when [getting impersonation tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html#get-all-impersonation-tokens-of-a-user): that API returns associated scopes.